# Sorting in C++ distributed across several frames

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

In the game I'm working on, I have a large amount of data stored in a vector that I would like to sort, but w/o impacting the performances of the game during that operation.
So is there (in the STL or others) an asynchronous algorithm allowing to sort any vector of data with a limited number of comparisons per frame (each requiring some computation), and providing the result after X frames of computation?

Comment: You might find some answers in [this article](http://larshagencpp.github.io/blog/2016/04/23/fast-incremental-sort) about incremental sorting.

Comment: Do remember to assess the **actual** performance impact of your sort before you do anything heroic! It might be faster than you think. (You may already have checked this, but you didn't say so explicitly).

Comment: yes, it can be various, I don't know in advance how much data I'll have to sort, and it might have a serious impact on the performance of the application - actually, a drop of framerate in a game.

Comment: my approach for this sorting algorithm would be "I don't care how much time (= number of times I execute this method) you spend sorting this list, I just don't want you to make more than 10 comparisons per execution" (as the comparison requires some computation, and the sorting is done for several objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std::partial_sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort/) for this, sorting small chunks of vector each iteration. After all chunks done you can use [inplace_merge](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/inplace_merge/) to merge sorted chunks pair-by-pair together and get finally sorted vector.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by frames? You could split your data parellize a merge sort using  `std::inplace_merge`.

Comment: Instead of doing synchronously the sorting in one execution of the method, I would call several times the same method to progress in the sorting, and spread its execution across time.
It's in a game, on several characters, so I don't want to have a drop of framerate like now if I have a lot of data to sort in one shot.